# How to fetch the details of database tables

Tags: java

How can i fetch details of derby database tables into a program in java. For example no. of columns in particular table.I tried Database Metadata but doesn't worked. Please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is neither a valid compiler error nor a valid runtime exception.

Comment: share what you have tried so that we can have a look

Comment: @ Arun P Johny here's code  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
   c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/AMDecalog.Trainees/MyDB", "root", "root");
  
   DatabaseMetaData dmd = c.getMetaData();
   

   ResultSet rs=dmd.getColumns(null, null,"tablename", null);
   System.out.println(rs);
   while (rs.next()) 
   {
                               //something
   
   }

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from t1 where 1<>1");
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    for(int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        md.getColumnName(i);
        md.getColumnType(i);
        ...
```

see ResultSetMetaData API for more info

Comment: thanks! but actually i want to achieve it using Database Meta Data